# Dell Inspiron 3542 b40 i5 8gb ram 1TBHD not shutting off

Tags: dual-boot, dell, shutdown, 16.04, windows-10

I've tried everything but I couldn't fix the problem. I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot with windows 10. Ubuntu works fine,but It gets stuck at loading screen on shutdown. Ubuntu has never froze on reboot. It freezes at 'reached target shutdown', also the computer hardware seems to be shutdown but the monitor keeps turned on displaying the loading screen.

I want to fix this and keep Ubuntu installed on my computer because It's way faster and better than windows to do simple tasks (not talking about gaming) but I can't use it if I can't shut it down. Also if I reboot Ubuntu and boot windows I can turn off the computer through windows but It's really not convenient when I need to shutdown the computer.

Comment: This may be a bug.  I have the same issue, the fix so far has not worked.  As a workaround turn your swap off before shutdown. It takes a while sometimes if the swap has a lot of data but the shutdown completes.  I use `sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff` then watch the swap deplete using system monitor, as soon as the swap is empty the `systemctl poweroff` will complete.  Hope that helps.  :)

Answer (score 1):

[Similar question in Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bios-uefi-kernel-bug-i-cant-turn-off-my-pc-reboot-power-down/2369/21) by a Manjaro user [tokakaro](https://forum.manjaro.org/users/totakaro) says **updating BIOS** fixes the problem:

> Shutdown is working now in my Laptop with Manjaro.
>
> I researched in the last days and I found a new update for my BIOS. I
>   made a bootable USB with FreeDOS for update from A10 to A11 and fix
>   my problem again... (before A00 to A10)
>
> Dell links (both at the same day... the reason why I didn't update
>   before):
>
> - [System BIOS A10 since 27 Jan 201613](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=JVYK4)
> - [System BIOS A11 since 27 Jan 201622](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=YVRKG&fileId=3486474654&osCode=&productCode=&categoryId=BI)

Comment: Wow THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've just installed the bios update and it worked. Ubuntu is finally shutting down